# How does this Python's list value assignment works in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have come across a strange behaviour in Python's value assignment. If I create a list such as  `List =[[0, 0], [0, 0]]` and want to change a value indexed 1 in the list indexed as 1 I simply use: `List[1][1] = 1`. However, this is not a case of the code below. Eventhough the list seems same as the one mentioned above, it assigns more values then I expect. Is there anyone who can explain how this work?

```py
size = 2
matrix = [[]]
for j in range(size):
    matrix[0].append(0)
for i in range(size-1):
    matrix.append(matrix[0])
matrix[1][1] = 1
print(str(matrix))
```

I would expect the output as `[[0, 0], [0, 1]]`, but the actual output is `[[0, 1], [0, 1]]`. Why is the value at position  `matrix[0][1]` assigned as 1??

Comment: You only work with one list inside your outer list. `matrix[0]`, i.e. matrix contains the same list twice. You need to explicitly copy it when you add it

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
matrix.append(matrix[0])
```

You're appending to `matrix` the reference to the object `matrix[0]` (which is a `list`), it isn't creating a new list.